# XPath 2.0 custom function invocation syntax analysis

Tags: parsing, xpath, syntax, xpath-2.0, custom-function

I was wondering whether there is any easy way of checking syntactic correctnes of XPath 2.0 expressions including checking correctness of custom functions invocations.

For example:

there is a custom function defined as follows:

```
<function signature="my:foo($p as number, $q as number) as number">
   <sequence value="$p + $q"/>
</function>
```

so this function should be invoked with the expression like:

```
my:foo(a, b)
```

However, we cannot check whether the function call is syntacticaly correct according to its definition using only XPath 2.0 parser. XPath 2.0 parser will accept expressions like:

```
my:foo(a)
my:foo(a, b, c, d, e)
my:foo((a, b, c, d))
```

The question is whether there is any easy way to check correctnes of custom functions invocations (without type checking, only number of arguments)?

Comment: In what context or with which tool do you use XPath, and why do you only have access to syntactic analysis? I would think that XPath compilation would raise errors on function calls with the wrong arguments.

Comment: I created my own language that extends XPath 2.0. Basicaly you can write any XPath 2.0 expression in this language but you can use different syntax for variables (not only $a is allowed). Users create expressions using this language and I need to parse these expressions, extract some information from it and convert these expressions to plain XPath 2.0 by replacing my variables with XPath 2.0 variables. Such expressions are later evaluated by a separate system module.

Answer (score 1):

Note that technically, we are talking here about the semantic correctness of the function call, not its syntactic correctness. That is, we're not checking simply that it conforms to the XPath grammar, but that the call makes sense in the context of the available function signatures.

I would expect most XPath engines to check semantic correctness at the same time as they check syntactic correctness. For example, if you process the expression using Saxon's interface `XPathCompiler.compile("my:foo(a, b)")`, the call will succeed only if `my:foo#2` is defined as a function in the static context, with declared argument types compatible with supplying element nodes as the arguments.

How to add functions to the static context is another question. You've given an XML-based definition of a function implementation:

```
<function signature="my:foo($p as number, $q as number) as number">
   <sequence value="$p + $q"/>
</function>
```

Turning that into something that Saxon understands will require some effort. There are two sides to it: making the XPath compiler understand the function signature, and making the XPath runtime understand the function body. I'm really not sure what you have in mind here.

Comment: thx for the comment, I was thinkng about XPath compiler understanding function signature, so that I can detect a mismatch between method invocation and its signature before it is detected during runtime

Comment: As I say, I would expect most XPath 2.0 implementations to detect such a mismatch at compile time.